# Is Model required or Optional in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to upload a excel file to the server, read contents, perform some validation and return those contents to the browser in raw html format.
My question is that what if My Controller can read the contents of the file and build html dynamically and sending the html content back to the client. Here Model is not being used, is it a bad design pattern?

Comment: In the situation you've described, your Model is the data you're supposed to use for rendering that Html. In theory, that Model should be passed to the view and you'll be using e.g. Razor Html helpers for rendering the page. I doubt this can be done easily the wrong way, for instance concatenating strings and forcing Html response. So I don't even see the benefit of not using MVC pattern. I only can guess the benefit is, you don't know MVC and this allows you to avoid using MVC in an MVC project. Perhaps if you give more context that might change this conclusion.

Comment: The Model-View-Controler pattern would be kind of wierd without 1/3 of what literally defines it. It can often happen that it appears that _this time_ you do not need to use a certain part. That can work out. Or later bite you in the butt. Usually we appply patterns to never even _risk_ being bitten in the butt, even if it is extra work right now. Usually you have to invest a bit of work, to save a ton of work later.

Comment: Voting to close your question, you are asking a silly question, the Model is not required, and whether it is a bad design pattern or not is entirely subjective to your requirements now and your potential requirements in the future

Answer (score 1):

Render your desired Html at Server Side in a single string
then put it in a Model with only one string , then send it to View and show it using Html.Raw() as following concept:

Model:

```
public class RenderedHtmlViewModel
{
      public string RenderedHtml {get;set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.RenderedHtml)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid doing this. You should construct a model based on the Excel file contents, and then you should create a view based on that model.

Comment: What if number of columns change? how to define a model in this case?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more specifics on what you're doing. Could you read all of the columns and rows into a 2D array? Then send that 2D array to the view and iterate through it with nested loops?